# How to design auto adjust number of column in gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

GridView with only SingleRow and Multiple Column.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPKcP.png]

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPKcP.png

Comment: Probably the image you posted was designed in according of buttons width.
If a button is too big then you may prevent add another button in the same row.

Comment: that is not a gridView definitely. It is a FlowLayout as for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line in ur GridView tag in xml.

```
 android:numColumns="auto_fit"
```